# Image on a textarea - JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to draw a form where there will be some textarea, on the textarea there will be a little image [the image's size will be smaller than the size of the textarea], and clicking on the image will call a function fx()
Can anyone code this for me in JavaScript/jquery/CSS ?

[image: Sample Image]

In this image the GO is an image, clicking on it will call Fx()

i tried with it and failed (and dont know how to attach a function on the image)

```
.searchform {
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px 5px;
}
.searchform input {
font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.searchform .searchfield {
background: #fff;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
width: 202px;
border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
outline: none;
}
.searchform .searchbutton {
color: #fff;
border: solid 1px #494949;
font-size: 11px;
height: 27px;
width: 27px;
}


<form class="searchform">
<input id="t" class="searchfield" value="Search..." type="text">
<input class="searchbutton" value="Go" type="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Are the height and width of the textarea known?

Comment: Do you want someone to do the work for you, or do you want help solving a problem? I would appreciate if you gave it a try your self first, and then ask the question if you are stuck. This is not "RentACoder".

Comment: @pekka i am using rows and cols of textarea, no width or height

Comment: @Martin, i tried but failed, so i'm looking for help, any help on the prob will be also appreciated !

Comment: @Sourav Could you please post your code that failed, would be easier to correct that, instead of writing it all again..

Comment: ["Can anyone code this for me"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer)

Comment: @Martin Hey martin, where are you ! i posted my code !

Comment: @Znarkus If you can not help, zip your mouth !

Comment: -1 for the comment related to Znarkus.

Comment: @Dr.Mobile dont you think it was like - i am asking a question on physics and he is giving answer about chemical reaction ?

Comment: @Sourav I'm sorry that I upset you. But if you want someone to code something for you, hire them. Ask us for help, not to code for you :)

Comment: Come on, i am telling to code just 10 or maximum 15 lines not about hundred or thousands of lines !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is

- Place the "go" element before the textarea, make it `position: absolute` so it hovers over the top left corner of the area
- Put a wrapper with `position: relative` around the elements
- Use jQuery's `.width()` and `.height()` functions to adjust the position of the "go" element.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="go">Go</div> 
<textarea id="area" rows=33 cols=22></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { position: relative }
#go { width: 16px; tpp: 16px; position: absolute; background-color: yellow }
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
$("#go").css("left", $("#area").width() - $("#go").width());
$("#go").css("top", $("#area").height() - $("#go").height());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WUnQW/

There's an even simpler approach that doesn't need JavaScript at all, but uses `display: inline-block` which won't work properly in IE6/7 (although I guess it could be made work in IE7 by using a `span` instead of a `div` for `wrapper`).

http://jsfiddle.net/WUnQW/6/

Comment: i made some change, now you can click on GO too :)

Comment: now there is a very little prob, the image hides some text, i tried with margin and padding  but failed !

Comment: @Sourav indeed! Padding doesn't seem to work on the textarea. Not sure whether there is a way around that.

Comment: @Madmartigan's solution is how I'd do it: set a padding on the wrapper div, remove the border from the textarea and add it to the wrapping div instead (to make it look like the textarea has a padding).

Comment: @Pekka Everything works fine, just a little prob, GO is blocking some text, plz fix that so user can see all the text in the textarea  http://jsfiddle.net/WUnQW/27/

Comment: @Sourav that is not fixable. You'd have to make the "GO" button a part of the text area, which is impossible.

Comment: Can you fix that in any other way ? the rest of the code is fine :) can you attach the GO on right side of the textarea ? that will be also OK !

Comment: @Sourav sorry, there is no other easy way that I can think of.  Regarding positioning it to the right of the area, add a `padding-right` to the wrapper element, and position it further to the right (`width() + 16` for example). Edit: You're on the right track with your fiddle, just increase the number

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place an image tag inside a textarea unless it's a background image. To work around this Use a div with contentEditable attribute. This will act like a textarea and will allow you to insert an `<img>` tag inside. That's how WYSIWYG editors work. Then with simpe CSS you can position the image bottom right.

```
<div contentEditable="true"> type here
 <img id="textimg" src="..." />
</div>
```

To run function `fx()` when image is clicked on you can do.

```
function fx() {
    alert('this is a function');
}
$('#textimg').click(fx);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6bCRJ/4/

Comment: i really appreciate your code but i dont need the image to be editable ! plz look at the above code ! And thnx for your code :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap image into an anchor `<div><a ... ><Image /></a>.</div>` then you can call the click attribute. Then use CSS to absolute position the `<div>`

Comment: how can i know the position to place the image on the textarea !

Comment: wrap a div around the textarea and the image. Position the image div against the parent div using relative position